# How to debug "Out of memory" from core?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I got a core from g_ascii_strdown() which said it got error while doing malloc() and it crashed. So if the process hit out-of-memory case, is there a way to find out, from core and gdb, which part of program (caller, stack or thread) allocated memory ?

In other words, If I have the core file. What kind of information exist in core file that I can use to find out memory allocations ?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "figure out all the allocated memory"? What, exactly, is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to find out which part of process/program allocated how much.

Comment: @spa, core is a dump of _program_ state at the moment of crash, and you need _system_ state. They are completely different -- to collect system state you will need to setup basic monitoring like `collectl`, etc. (or collect _system core_ a.k.a. crashdump/kdump/etc.)

Comment: I do have the core file. What kind of information exist in core file that I can use to find out memory allocations.

Comment: What kind of program is this? You should edit your question to improve it!

Comment: "*... got a core from g_ascii_strdown() which said it got error while doing malloc() and it crashed. So if the process hit out-of-memory case,  ...*" if running out-of-memory `malloc()` does not crash, but would return `NULL`. So if you observe a crash inside `malloc()` this most certainly does **not** indicate an out-of-memroy situation, but some sort of memory-(management-)corruption. The latter might have happend (much?) earlier then the moment of the crash. Use a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) to test your program's handling of memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it most certainly is an XY-problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: @alk: This is a totally reasonable question, sometimes a core is all you have to go off of because the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @myaut: not necessarily, usually when developing new software if you encounter an out of memory error it's your new software

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, `malloc` does not save any book-keeping information that would allow you to figure out what parts of your program allocated the memory. Since that information isn't in the live process, it won't be in the core-dump either.

If you want to figure that out, you'll need to use some `malloc` debug library/program instead. I'd normally recommend [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for this, since it contains an excellent `malloc` debugger, but Valgrind only works on live processes. There might be some alternative `malloc` library that you can link against that keeps such information around in such a way that it would also be saved in core-dumps, but if there is, I can't say I know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like some [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on some *reproducible* run exhibiting the issue (you'll need to start the program again under `valgrind`). You might not be able to find the issue post-mortem using the `core` dump alone

BTW, the [glib running](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html) documentation also suggests calling `g_mem_set_vtable (glib_mem_profiler_table)` very early at startup (at the beginning of your `main`)

See also the [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/)

At last, it is not important to know which part of the memory exhausted. The available memory is a whole process thing. When running your program of pid 1234, use `cat /proc/1234/maps` & see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)